# Raster calculator: Minidump error

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, minidump

I have the following problem with the **raster calculator** in **QGIS v. 2.14**:
I have several raster (**TIFF**) which I need for my calculation. Everytime when I start the calculation I get an **error** message: **Minidump in C**. After the error message appears QGIS closes.

I searched for this problem but I haven't found a resolution yet. Maybe it is a plugin problem? Maybe someone has a tip for me!

Comment: Are you using the latest bugfix version of 2.14?

Answer (score 1):

You should file a proper bug report over at http://hub.qgis.org/issues and attach your data. That's the only way to get something like this fixed.

Comment: @M.Liekefett  If this has answered your question, please consider voting and accepting.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)